# Webpack console output

Tags: webpack, bundler, transpiler

My webpack output console log is this:

```
$ webpack --progress --config webpack.config.test.js
{ NODE_ENV: 'development' }
{ WEBPACK_BUNDLE: true, WEBPACK_BUILD: true }
assets by status 1.46 MiB [cached] 8 assets
assets by path . 1.58 KiB
  asset css/styles.css 1.01 KiB [compared for emit] (name: main) 1 related asset
  asset index.html 584 bytes [compared for emit]
Entrypoint main 543 KiB (1.58 MiB) = runtime.0a95cdc1c076b6c7fd14.js 6.7 KiB vendors.8175084d63678640b295.js 532 KiB css/styles.css 1.01 KiB main.cd02394e31eece531e82.js 3.54 KiB 9 auxiliary assets
runtime modules 3.39 KiB 7 modules
cacheable modules 533 KiB (javascript) 568 bytes (css/mini-extract)
  javascript modules 533 KiB
    modules by path ../ 531 KiB
      ../node_modules/lodash/lodash.js 531 KiB [built] [code generated]
      ../css/app.css 50 bytes [built] [code generated]
      ../css/app1.css 50 bytes [built] [code generated]
    modules by path ./*.js 1.43 KiB
      ./index.js 1.03 KiB [built] [code generated]
      ./testC.js 409 bytes [built] [code generated]
  css modules 568 bytes
    css ../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!../css/app.css 522 bytes [built] [code generated]
    css ../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!../css/app1.css 46 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.47.0 compiled successfully in 1178 ms
Done in 2.12s.
```

I want this structure

```
Hash: aaaf5afc6582f3222f55
Version: webpack 1.12.14
Time: 1175ms
   Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
index.js  677 kB       0  [emitted]  main
chunk    {0} index.js (main) 643 kB [rendered]
    [0] ./src/app.js 574 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]
    [1] ./~/react/react.js 56 bytes {0} [built]
    [2] ./~/react/lib/React.js 1.49 kB {0} [built]
    [3] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOM.js 3.71 kB {0} [built]
    [4] ./~/process/browser.js 2.06 kB {0} [built]
```

Iam using webpack 5.0

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking to make this output less noisy.

In our codebase we have

`console.info(stats.toString(config.stats))`, where `stats` is of type `Configuration`

If you have something similar you can change the formatting instead of doing a plain `.toString()`